# Find all pattern in expression

Tags: function-construction, simplifying-expressions, replacement

Consider this problem: I have a functional $\mathcal{F}$ acting on some function $n(t)$ such that

$$
\mathcal{F}[n(t)]=0
$$

$$
\mathcal{F}[n^*(s)n(t)]=\alpha(t,s)
$$

$$
\mathcal{F}[n(s)n(t)]=0
$$

Now I want to implement $\mathcal{F}$ on an expression, e.g.

```
expr = (Conjugate[Integrate[f[s] *n[s], {s, 0, t}]] + 
     g[t]) (Integrate[r[q] *n[q], {q, 0, t}] + n[t]*p[t]) // ExpandAll
```

This contains 4 terms:

1.

```
Conjugate[Integrate[f[s]*n[s], {s, 0, t}]]*Integrate[n[q]*r[q], {q, 0, t}]
```

This should transform to

$$
\int_0^t\int_0^tdsdqf^*(s)r(q) n^*(s)n(q) \rightarrow \int_0^t\int_0^tdsdqf^*(s)r(q) \alpha(q,s)
$$

2.

```
 g[t]*Integrate[n[q]*r[q], {q, 0, t}]
```

which $\mathcal{F} \rightarrow 0$ due to rule #1

3.

```
 Conjugate[Integrate[f[s]*n[s], {s, 0, t}]]*n[t]*p[t]
```

This transforms as
$$
\int_0^tds f^*(s)n^*(s)n(t)p(t) \rightarrow \int_0^tds f^*(s)\alpha(t,s)p(t)
$$

4.

```
g[t]*n[t]*p[t]
```

$\mathcal{F} \rightarrow  0 $ due to rule 1.

For this expression, I can first deal with the `Conjugate` and `Integrate`
by

```
expr = expr //. {Conjugate[Integrate[f_, l_]] :> 
       Integrate[Conjugate[f], l]} //. {Conjugate[a_*b_] :> 
      Conjugate[a]*Conjugate[b]} //. {a_*Integrate[f_, l_] :> 
     Integrate[a*f, l]} //. {Integrate[f1_, l1_] Integrate[f2_, 
      l2_] :> Integrate[f1*f2, l1, l2]}
```

followed by, e.g.

```
expr /. {Conjugate[n[x_]] n[y_] :> a[x, y]}
```

Then filter out expressions that contains only one $n(t)$:

```
Table[{expr[[i]], Count[expr[[i]], n[x_], 10]}, {i, 1, 
   Length[expr]}] // TableForm
```

Is there a more automatic/robust way to do this?